# How to customize tab bar with icons?

Tags: java, android

Can someone explain to me what I should add exactly to this code from this [website](http://www.materialdoc.com/tabs/):

```
III. To change tab icon use TabLayout.Tab#setIcon method. You can get TabLayout.Tab object via TabLayout#getTabAt method, which accept tab index as parameter.

...
//after initialization TabLayout and ViewPager
TabLayout.Tab tabCall = tabLayout.getTabAt(ITEM_CALL);  
tabCall.setIcon(R.drawable.selector_call);

//repeat this code for all your tabs
...
```

Because I get `tabLayout` and `ITEM_CALL` in red!

[image]

Comment: Do you declare your TabLayout as they suggest?  i.e. `TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);`

Comment: @DanielNugent  ok I did that, thanks. how do fix `ITEM_CALL`?

Comment: That is a constant that you need to declare.  Also, you should be calling `setIcon()` in `onCreate()`, not in `getPageTitle()`

Comment: @DanielNugent What does this constant represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first create the selector xml files, and place them in your drawable folder, and those selector files need to reference valid drawables for the selected and non-selected states.

Then, just set the tab icons in `onCreate()` of the Activity.

Here is what your Activity should look like in order to show three tabs, with each tab showing only an icon:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout.Tab tabCall = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
        tabCall.setIcon(R.drawable.selector_call);

        TabLayout.Tab tabHeart = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
        tabHeart.setIcon(R.drawable.selector_heart);

        TabLayout.Tab tabContacts = tabLayout.getTabAt(2);
        tabContacts.setIcon(R.drawable.selector_contacts);
    }

    class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new CallFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new HeartFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new ContactsFragment();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Each tab needs its own selector xml file, here is an example of what the selector for the third tab should look like:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/contacts_selected" />

    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/contacts_unselected" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

declare this as a constant in your MainActivity class

```
private static final Striing ITEM_CALL = 0;
```

do this declaration on your onCreate() :

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
```

then create selector_call.xml in the drawable folder with this code :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_call_selected" />

    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_call_unselected" />

</selector>
```

Comment: I get error:`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.setIcon(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: At this line: `tabCall.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);`

Comment: did you put selector_call.xml in the drawable folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- coordinate layout add more than one widget in systematic way and 
  inhance others property-->

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".Tab_Bar">

<!--Add space for toolbar and tab bars-->

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"> 

    <!-- "?attr/actionBarSize" means same size as 
         original Toolbar size
      "scroll|enterAlways" here "scroll" means when 
      we scroll viewPager up it is scrolled up and "enterAlways" means when 
      we scroll up it reappears -->

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

      <!--tabGravity="fill", if you want the tabs to be occupied the 
       fullwidth of the screen
       If you want to keep your tabs horizontally centered, assign 
       tabGravity="center"
       app:tabMode=> Defines the mode of the tab layout.
        In our case the value should be “fixed” as we have limited number of 
        tabs but if you have many number of tabs where there is insufficient 
        space on the screen to fit all of them the you can  change the 
        app:tabMode to "scrollable".-->

     <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#F4F7FA"
        app:tabGravity="fill">

         <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="One"
             android:icon="@drawable/one_img"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Two"
             android:icon="@drawable/two_img"/>

 </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: Okay, sure Thank you!